# What is the meaning of "clubbed to death?"

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of "clubbed to death?" The song *Clubbed to Death* was the reason of my question :)

Comment: You whack someone on the head [with a club, usually] until they die. (Or *you* die of exhaustion.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's also a song by Rob Dugan, aka DJ Rob D, best known for the appearance of the "Kurayamino mix" of it on the *Matrix* soundtrack (in the "woman in the red dress" scene).  In that instance, it's a double entendre between Dusty's answer and F'x's, or variants on the latter like "having been immersed in the club scene until dead or wishing one were".

Comment: That song was the reason of my question :)

Comment: @Martin You should have said so.

Comment: @Jim Balter, yes you are right.

Comment: Sorry to be a pedant, y'all, but this is english.stackexchange.com after all! A 'song' is a set of words set to music. You *sing* a song. As Clubbed to Death has no words it is therefore 'just' a piece of music. :)

Comment: As to the song, watch the official videoclip here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YCGtT_FRYg
You will find your answer ;) I could not describe it better than this user "SevaVideo": In a world full of deceit , we're moving backwards like mindless sheep.
We need to start to move against the system
How, one way or another, we try to destroy each other.
Love can freeze time, and create it's own reality.
Falls and rises again, like we all should do.
That wall represents all that keeps us from being the best we can.
When you overcome that wall that keeps you back you Come back better, stronger, wise

Comment: Could it also be interpreted as "to unite; combine; join together"? For instance, a group of people in a suicide mission.

Comment: @CalculusKnight: There's probably no compelling reason to read it that way in the context, but it's an interesting interpretation.

Answer (score 17):

To *club* something is to beat it, usually with a large blunt-force weapon (e.g. a club).  So if something is *clubbed to death*, then it's beaten with some large weapon until it's dead.

Comment: More often someone than something

Comment: @nico People are things. some*thing* is more general and includes rats, weeds, etc. The phrase can also be used metaphorically to refer to destroying an inanimate object, such as a statue or a computer.

Comment: Personally I would not use "thing" referring to people...

Comment: @nico well, we all qualify surely - but yes, that way sociopathy lies...

Comment: @nico It's appropriate in this context. @Marc As for sociopathy -- personally I would not club anyone to death, but that's neither here nor there.

Comment: Hmm, any comment on the down vote?

Answer (score 7):

Also, it could also be a pun on the standard meaning (see Dusty’s answer), but actually mean *“to party ’til you’re dead”*.

Answer (score 0):

["Clubbed to Death"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clubbed_to_Death) is an album, a band, a film, and a song.

For the quite different phrase "clubbed to death", see Dusty's answer. Of course, that could appear capitalized in a title or headline, such as [this](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748703818204576206560556232614.html) where the phrase is used metaphorically and as a pun on "rugby club".

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to what people are saying being clubbed to death could also be taken in a different way suggesting that Mr Hyde (for example in Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde) was taking it as a joke whilst he beat Crew as if he was a golf ball.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. At the moment, this reads more like a comment than an answer. When you have accumulated more reputation you may post comments.